# How to capture the traffic and monitoring application network activity in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I am using JetBrains Rider and I want to monitor and debug the network activity of my app. I know there are tools like Fiddler or Wireshark that can capture the traffic, but I want to see it inside Rider's IDE, if possible. Is there a way to do that? I've searched the documentation and the settings, but I couldn't find anything related to network monitoring or debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, we do not have such a tool. I think it would be better to use our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER and submit a request.